# Comparing a Multiplication

Tags: algorithm, numbers

I am having an Array `A` and `B` , we multiply all elements of array `A`  and let this value called `MulA` , similary we do for `B` call this value `MulB`.

Now we want to compare these value which one is greater, Can we do without actually multiplying the elements, since value is of order `10^10` and `array length` is upto `10^6` we cannot store our result?

Comment: Why not use `int64_t`? Its max value is 9 223 372 036 854 775 807, which is more than 9×10¹⁸.

Comment: You haven't mentioned important thing - what is type of elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid large products, you can compare the sum of the logs: `sum(log a for a in A)` to `sum(log b for b in B)`. That's because `(a1*a2*a3*...*an) = exp(log(a1)+log(a2)+...+log(an))`, and `exp` is an increasing function.

This will introduce some numerical error (since `log` is not exactly computable), but it'll work well enough in practice unless the products are very close to each other.

Note, this works both when the product is huge, and also when the product is tiny (for example if the elements were probabilities).

Answer (score 0):

Use 64 bit integer (`long long` in C++) which can hold upto `9 x 10^18` (2^63 - 1). And no, there is no way to compare two lists multiplications without multiplying them (modular arithmetic rules for multiplication won't work here).

> since value is of order 10^10 and array length is upto 10^6 we cannot
>   store our result?

In worst case, the multiplied value will be 10^(10^7) which can't fit in any data-type. So you need to use Big Integer here which does everything in string form under the hood.

If you need a simple Big Integer implementation in C++, I can provide one. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer. By the way, checked the OP's profile and found he is a C++ fan :P

Comment: @Dukeling No. It will require 10^10000000(one more 0 than yours) which I mentioned above :) And (10^10)^(10^6) is not same as 10^1000000 as you mentioned.